# Suppose that $f^2$ is Riemann integrable, is it true that $f$ is Riemann integrable?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[a,b] → R$ be a bounded function on [a,b]. Suppose that $f^2$ is Riemann integrable, is it true that $f$ is Riemann integrable?

My approach:
I planned to let $f^{2}(x)=x$ and is bounded on [-1,1]. And show that $f^{2}(x)$ is continuous so it is integrable. However, $f(x)=\sqrt x$ is not continuous on [-1,1]. So, it is not integrable.

May I know if I know if the approach is correct?

Comment: You cannot have $f^{2}(x)=x$ on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Is $f$ *defined* on $[-1,1]$? In the problem, you start with $f$ on $[a,b]$ and then obtain $f^2$.

Comment: See  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/244409/42969 for a correct answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $f^2$ is Riemann Integrable is $f$ always Riemann Integrable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244409/if-f2-is-riemann-integrable-is-f-always-riemann-integrable)

Comment: @MartinR  Thank you, I think it answered my question.

Comment: @user1551 Thank you!

Comment: I know you already have an answer, but let me point out that the statement "$f(x)$ is not continuous, so it is not integrable" is false. Continuity *implies* integrability. It is not equivalent to integrability. There are plenty of integrable functions that are not continuous, for example, the Heaviside function $$H(x) = \begin{cases}0&x \le 0\\1&x > 0\end{cases}$$ (though named for a mathematician, there is no other function who name is so accidentally *appropriate*, which is probably why so many people remember it).